# How to change the color of the text in below code?

Tags: css, html

```
<div style="font-color: #ff0000">Where would you like to go today?</div>
```

I am trying to change the color of this text, but it is not being reflected in the code.I searched a lot, but is displaying default black color always.

Comment: remove the ``font-`` it is just ``color:``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-color` is not valid css property use `color:#ff0000`

```
<div style="color: #ff0000">Where would you like to go today?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use:
    color: #ff0000;

2) probably you should take a look at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

use color property instead

Read More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

```
style="color: #ff0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

as stated by others the `font-color` is not a valid property so you should use `color`
The code will be the following:

```
<div style="color: #ff0000">Where would you like to go today?</div>
```

Below a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/8up32r2v/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property named **font-color** in css. We can use **color** for the same.

```
div{
    color: ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Font-color is not valid css property.

The ways to achieve what you are trying to can be:

```css
div{color: #ff0000}
```

```html
<div>Where would you like to go today?</div>
```

OR

```html
<font size="3" color="red">Where would you like to go today?</font></p>
```

Please note that:

### The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5

---

OR

```html
<div style="color: #ff0000">Where would you like to go today?</div>
```